# change background color using canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I made a function on the canvas to cut an image and change its background color, but it does not change to the white color that I try to put
this was the code i made

````
  const image = await createImage(imageSrc);
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (!ctx) {
    return null;
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.drawImage(image, 150, 200, 500, 300, 60,60, 500, 300);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toBlob((file) => {
      file.name = 'cropped.jpeg';
     resolve({ file: file, url: URL.createObjectURL(file) });
    }, 'image/jpeg');
  });
 }```

I want to make the background of the image white, but it is always coming out black and does not change the color
````

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.fill()` needs a path to fill. The quickest thing to do would be draw a rectangle the full size of the image, then run fill. You'll have to fill in the appropriate width/height for your image.

```
  ...
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.drawImage(image, 150, 200, 500, 300, 60,60, 500, 300);
  ...
```

Comment: i need to paint the background but your solution overlays the image

Comment: he is doing it inside the image area, overlapping it